# Disable only the iOS bounce not inside scrolling (web app/html/css)

Tags: jquery, ios, twitter-bootstrap, bounce

I'm creating a Web App using Bootstrap ('apple-mobile-web-app-capable') and I need to remove the iOS bounce.

I already tried other solutions, like iNoBounce.js, Nonbounce.js, "html {     height  : 100%; overflow: hidden; }" and other suggestions.

Still the same problem, the bounce stops, but the inside scrolling (like a table or div, normal page scrolling) stops too.

I want to remove only the bounce from the 'web app'.

Any true fix for that?

**Edit:**

This is what **I want to remove** (got the image from another S.O. question)
[image]

Comment: When you say "remove the bounce" do you mean -- do not allow the scroll to extend past the bounds? Or do you mean allow it to extend but don't bounce it back into place? Or something else?

Comment: Included one image showing the "problem". Thanks

Comment: Can you reproduce this problem using iNoBounce and a minimal app? If so, you might want to open an issue with them.  Looking at their code, it seems like it should be doing what you want.

Comment: Yes, if I use iNoBounce the bounce stops, but the main content stop scrolling on the page too.